# MySQL sort by some list

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of numbers: `7,1,3,2,123,55` (which are the ids of existing records)

I have a mysql table with the colums `id` and `name`, where `id` is an integer primary key. 
I want to select records from this table, but in a specific order, for example `7`,`1`,`3`,`2`,`123`,`55`.

- Is it possible to do this in MyISAM within query, without any post processing?
- What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Since `1 < 3 < 77 < 123`, a simple `ORDER BY id` would suffice.

If, however, you want to order this way: `77, 3, 123, 1`, then you could use function [**`FIELD()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```sql
SELECT id, name
FROM mytable 
WHERE id IN (77, 3, 123, 1) 
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 77, 3, 123, 1)
```

**If your query matches more rows than you list in `FIELD`**

`FIELD` returns `0` when a row does not match any of the ids you list, i.e. a number smaller than the numbers returned for listed ids. This means, if your query matches more rows than the ones you list, those rows will appear first. For example:

```sql
SELECT id, name
FROM mytable 
WHERE id IN (77, 3, 123, 1, 400) 
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 77, 3, 123, 1)
```

In this example, the row with ID `400` will appear first. If you want those rows to appear last, simply reverse the list of IDs and add `DESC`:

```sql
SELECT id, name
FROM mytable 
WHERE id IN (77, 3, 123, 1, 400) 
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 1, 123, 3, 77) DESC
```

Comment: It does not work ... i try this

     SELECT                                       
          *                                       
                                                  
     FROM                                         
          lalala      
                                                  
     WHERE                                        
          id IN (8,9,4,5)    
                                                  
     ORDER BY                                     
          FIELD(8,9,4,5)  


AND GOT:

4,5,8,9 ... records

Comment: @publikz.com You have to use ORDER BY FIELD(**id**, 8,9,4,5)