# Order items in MySQL by a fixed list?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am going to have a fixed list of items to order by that I won't know until I run the query since there is a randomization step.

I would like to have something like the following:

Assume that `is_launch_set` will return 1, 3, 7, 11 but have been randomized to below:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE is_launch_set=1 ORDER BY id values (3,11,7,1);
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? I was thinking maybe a `find_in_set` but not really sure.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [MySQL Sort by some list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810793/), although this one attracted a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can do that by using either:

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '3,11,7,1')
```

or

```
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 3, 11, 7, 1)
```

or

```
ORDER BY CASE id WHEN 3 THEN 0
                WHEN 11 THEN 1
                 WHEN 7 THEN 2
                 WHEN 1 THEN 3
                        ELSE 4
         END
```

Comment: are you sure the find in set would work - before I asked the quesiton, that's what I thought the answer would be but the ordering seems different each time. Are there any config settings or anything else. The field answer looks good.

Comment: @timpone: I'm sure it works. You could put `FIND_IN_SET(id, '3,11,7,1')` to the `SELECT` to make sure it returns what expected

Comment: Do you have any information on which of these approaches is the fastest performing? Is there anything one can do to speed it up besides putting an index on the `id` field?

Comment: @Patrick M: you could try it first. Performance optimization requires personal checks

Comment: That last one is really useful for clarity of the code, thanks.

Comment: Just tested each of the first two methods using 10k records from a 250k record set. FIND_IN_SET took about 4.5 seconds, FIELD 500ms.

Comment: @Synexis: they perform similar operation with full scan. So it does not matter if there is minor difference between them.

Comment: For anyone interested [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/109126/57479) [@rolandomysqldba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/877/rolandomysqldba) shared some details about how this works

Answer (score 0):

In mys sql 8.0 it order only by the first column - 3 in this case:

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '3,11,7,1')
```

With this example it worked, but upside. you'll see the 3 last, then 11, then 7 etc.

```
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 3, 11, 7, 1)
```

If you chose this example, you'll see the 1 first, then 7, then 11 etc.

```
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 3, 11, 7, 1) DESC
```