# How to get random rows including one specific id row

Tags: mysql

I currently have a query, where I SELECT * from different tables that is `!= $this->player_id` -> this works fine.

And looks like the following:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT pi . * , p . *
    FROM player_img pi, player p
    WHERE pi.player_img_category_id = $this->category_id
    AND pi.player_img_player_id = p.player_id
    AND pi.player_img_player_id != $this->player_id";
```

**What I now want to do is a bit different:**

- SELECT random results and order by limit 10
- Inbetween the random results **ONE specific row needs to be there** - this row should be based on `$this->player_id`

To just get the random results, I guess I can just do something like:

`ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10`

-however how I make sure that my specific row is included:

`pi.player_img_player_id == $this->player_id` - this I have no idea on.
Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
Allinone's answer does what im looking to do- as bonus question im wondering if its possible to SORT the query results by ASC p.player_firstname with his example??

Comment: how about two calls.. 1) Random limit 9  2) The row you want.... then you order by rand()

Comment: @gtgaxiola Make sure if you do that, the original `limit 9` query filters out the matching record, so you end up with 10 unique records. You can do this in one query with a union as well.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `UNION` with two queries but with different conditions

```
SELECT q.* FROM (
    SELECT pi . * , p . *
    FROM player_img pi, player p
    WHERE pi.player_img_category_id = $this->category_id
    AND pi.player_img_player_id = p.player_id
    AND pi.player_img_player_id != $this->player_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT pi . * , p . *
    FROM player_img pi, player p
    WHERE pi.player_img_category_id = $this->category_id
    AND pi.player_img_player_id = p.player_id
    AND pi.player_img_player_id = $this->player_id 
) q ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

Comment: you are applying random order on the entire result set, how will it make sure that player is present?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FIND_IN_SET() or FIELD() functions for this.  Your order by clause would look like this:

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(pi.player_img_player_id, '$this->player_id') desc, rand()
```

See more: [mysql order by a fixed list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940402/mysql-order-by-a-fixed-list)

Comment: AllInOne > Thanks so much - this seems to be just what I need to make it work! Really appreciate the effort. One bonus question: Is it possible to SORT the query results by ASC p.player_firstname somehow?

Comment: I don't see how you could use this technique to do that (maybe someone else could).  I think you'd have to approach it differently, like with a sub-select which would be less efficient.  Perhaps you could sort your results in PHP?

Comment: You might want to add your sorting question as a separate question in SO if you feel it needs more attention.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion AllInOne - I tried editing my question. Ill just keep it open a little more and accept your answer asap - hopefully some additional help will popup