# Sort records by the order of IN clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code to insert data into an array called `$usersEmails`:

```
while($get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
    $userOne = $get['UserOne'];
    $userTwo = $get['UserTwo'];
    if($userOne != $id){
        array_push($usersEmails, $userOne);
    }else if($userTwo != $id){
        array_push($usersEmails, $userTwo);
    }
}
```

Then I have made a query using this array:

```
$query = 'SELECT `Email` FROM `users` 
          WHERE `Id` IN ('.implode(',', array_map('intval', $usersEmails)).')';
```

This code generates results ordered by `users.Id`, but I want these IDs to be ordered in the same order as they appear in my array.

In other words, I want the IDs to be output from `0 --> end of array`

Comment: any help guys? I really need an answer

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking.  You might want to try rephrasing the question.

Comment: you have `while($get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run))` yet your query's variable is `$query`. Plus, is `$usersEmails` treated as an array? I've been staring at that for a while, and couldn't come up with anything. Echo/var_dump to see what's going in there or not, and how.

Comment: you asked, you received (just not a magical answer). So, how about letting us know what's going on or not? I won't be keeping this tab open any much longer.

Comment: `$usersEmails` are integers?

Comment: @chris85 yes they are integers and I want to select all the ids in that array

Comment: "select by the array of users table Id not by using my array id".  What exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: guys look :
`Where Id In($anyArray)` it search database and if result exist in array then it select it while i don't want that I want it to select the first index in my arrray then the second then the third and so on

Comment: You want to search finding the lowest `id`?

Comment: now the lowest not the highest i want to search by using my array element arrangement

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940402/mysql-order-by-a-fixed-list)?

Comment: @PatrickQ WOW MAN THATS EXACTLY WHAT I WANT! THANKS :D

Comment: sorry guys for not expressing my question good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your sql query `order by` and use `field`:

```
$query = 'select `Email`
          from `users` 
          where `Id` in (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $usersEmails)) . ')
          order by field(`Id`, ' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $usersEmails)) . ')
```