# Pushing Items to end of stack (part 2)

Tags: python, mysql

I have the following code which gets items to present to a user:

```
SELECT * FROM main_cue WHERE group_id IN (1,2,3,4) GROUP BY group_id;
>>> 1,2,3,4
```

However, I want to provide a specific ordering to this, such that (1) I have a list of items to push to the end of the stack **In the exact ordering I specify** and (2) the items that are not in the list will be ordered by id ASC. For example:

```
items_to_push_to_end_of_stack_in_this_exact_order = [3,2]
```

The new ordering would then be:

```
>>> [1,4,3,2]
1) 1 # first item by ID asc, not in `items_to_push_to_end_of_stack_in_this_exact_order`
2) 4 # second item by ID asc, not in `items_to_push_to_end_of_stack_in_this_exact_order`
3) 3 # items_to_push_to_end_of_stack_in_this_exact_order
4) 2 # items_to_push_to_end_of_stack_in_this_exact_order
```

How would I do this in mysql?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL sort by some list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810793/mysql-sort-by-some-list)

Comment: @Cfreak I think the above question is not just using the `ORDER BY FIELD(something)` that the other question and answers use. This is more of a composite sorting, using that method along with others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to specify the ordering, then use `order by`:

```
ORDER BY

    // First, Put "2" and "3" at the end of the stack
   (group_id IN (2, 3)) ASC,

   // Second, order the items not in the list by the `group_id`
   (CASE WHEN group_id NOT IN (2, 3) THEN group_id END) ASC,

   // Third, order the items in the list by the ordering you specify
   FIELD(group_id, 3, 2)
```

This is a bit complicated.  The first clause puts "2" and "3" at the end.  The second orders the rest by `group_id`.  The third orders the last set by the ordering you specify.

Answer (score 0):

Using Gordon's answer and the code I currently have, this is what worked:

```
passed_on_group_ids_as_str = ','.join(passed_on_group_ids) # convert the list to csv

cues_per_group = Cue.objects.raw('''SELECT * FROM main_cue WHERE group_id IN %s GROUP BY group_id 
                                        ORDER BY (group_id IN (%s)) ASC,
                                        (CASE WHEN group_id NOT IN (%s) THEN group_id END) ASC,
                                        FIELD(group_id, %s)''', 
                                    (group_ids, passed_on_group_ids_as_str, passed_on_group_ids_as_str, passed_on_group_ids_as_str))
```