# Sort SQL array based on months of string type

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have the following `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT `facility_name`, `day`, `month`, `year`, `start_time`, `end_time`
FROM reservation_db
WHERE user_id = '$userID'
ORDER BY `facility_name` ASC, `year` ASC, `day` ASC, `start_time` ASC, `end_time` ASC"
```

It works fine, but in my table I also have a column `month` that contains the months as **strings** (i.e. "Ian", "Feb", "Mar", etc). Changing the type of data stored in the column is no longer an option right now.. How can I use `ORDER BY` to also sort those?

Comment: You can try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810793/mysql-sort-by-some-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `case` expression to you order by, where you return each month's number:

```
order by case `month` when 'Jan' then 1
                      when 'Feb' then 2
                      when 'Mar' then 3
                      ...
                      when 'Dec' then 12
         end
```