# Adding a custom sorting to listing with an aggregate in shopware 6

Tags: sorting, aggregate, shopware, shopware6

I am trying to build a custom sorting for the product listings in shopware 6.
I want to include a foreign table (entity is: leasingPlanEntity), get the min of one of the fields of that table (period_price) and then order the search result by that value.

I have already built a Subscriber, and try it like that, what seems to work.

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        //ProductListingCollectFilterEvent::class => 'addFilter'
        ProductListingCriteriaEvent::class => ['addCriteria', 5000]
    ];
}

public function addCriteria(ProductListingCriteriaEvent $event): void
{
    $criteria = $event->getCriteria();
    $criteria->addAssociation('leasingPlan');
    $criteria->addAggregation(new MinAggregation('min_period_price', 'leasingPlan.periodPrice'));

    // Sortierung hinzufügen.
    $availableSortings = $event->getCriteria()->getExtension('sortings') ?? new ProductSortingCollection();

    $myCustomSorting = new ProductSortingEntity();
    $myCustomSorting->setId(Uuid::randomHex());
    $myCustomSorting->setActive(true);
    $myCustomSorting->setTranslated(['label' => 'My Custom Sorting at runtime']);
    $myCustomSorting->setKey('my-custom-runtime-sort');
    $myCustomSorting->setPriority(5);
    $myCustomSorting->setFields([
        [
            'field' => 'leasingPlan.periodPrice',
            'order' => 'asc',
            'priority' => 1,
            'naturalSorting' => 0,
        ],
    ]);

    $availableSortings->add($myCustomSorting);

    $event->getCriteria()->addExtension('sortings', $availableSortings);
}
```

Is this already the right way to get the min(periodPrice)? Or is it taking just a random value out of the leasingPlan table to define the sort-order?

I didn't find a way, to define the min_period_price aggregate value in the `$myCustomSorting->setFields` Methods.

---

**Update 1**

Some days later, I asked a less complex question in the shopware community on slack:

*Is it possible to use the DAL to define a subquery for an association in the product-listing?
It should generate something like:*

```
FROM
JOIN (
  SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY ... ORDER BY ...
) AS ...
```

The answer there was:

`Don't think so`

---

**Update 2**

I also did an in-deep anlysis of the DAL-Query-Builder, and it really seems to be not possible, to perform a subquery with the current version.

---

**Update 3 - Different approach**

A different approach might be, to define custom fields in the main entity. Every time a change is made on the main entity, the values of this custom fields should be recalculated.
It is a lot of overhead work, to realize this. Especially when the fields you are adding, are dependend on other data like the availability of a product in the store, for example.

So check, if it is worth the extra work. Would be better, to have a solution for building subqueries.

Comment: Can the subquery be eventually replaced by a normal JOIN? 
Can you run the subquery separately and in-cooperate its result in the original query? Does this one help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70023661/pull-certain-products-to-front-by-adding-custom-sql-to-criteria/70113483#70113483 ?

Comment: We stick with the custom-field solution now, also it required a lot of extra work to be done, like writing listeners at some points where the values might change in frontend and backend.

Also I am not sure, if your solution will be performant enough with large product-databases with many variants that have options themself. That in mind, the pre-calculated way we chose, might be even worth the extra work for us.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it seems that in your case there is no easy way to achieve this, if I understand the issue correctly.

Consider the following: for each product you can have multiple `leasingPlan` entities, and I assume that for a given context (like a specific sales channel or listing) that still holds. This means that you would have to sort the `leasingPlan` entities by price, then take the one with the lowest price, and then sort the products by their lowest-price `leasingPlan`'s price.

There seems to be no other way to achieve that, and unfortunately for you, sorting is applied at the end, even if it is sort of a subquery.

So, for example, if you have the following snippet

```
$criteria = $event->getCriteria();
$criteria->addAssociation('leasingPlan');
$criteria->getAssociation('leasingPlan')
    ->addSorting(new FieldSorting('price', FieldSorting::ASCENDING))
    ->setLimit(1)
;
```

The actual price-sorting would be applied AFTER the `leasingPlan` entities are fetched - essentially the results would be sorted, meaning that you would not get the cheapest leasing plan per product, instead getting the first one.

You can only do something like that with filters, but in this case there is nothing to filter by - I assume you don't have one `leasingPlan` per SalesChannel or per language, so that you could limit that list to just one entry that could be used for sorting

That is not to mention that this could not be included in a ProductSortingEntity, but you could always work around that by plugging into the appropriate events and modifying the criteria during runtime

I see two ways to resolve your issue

1. Making another table which would store the cheapest `leasingPlan` per product and just using that as your association
2. Storing the information about the cheapest `leasingPlan`s in e.g. cache and using that for filtering (caution: a mistake here would probably break the sorting, for example if you end up with too few or too many `leasingPlan`s per product)

```
public function applyCustomSorting(ProductListingCriteriaEvent $event): void
{
    // One leasingPlan per one product
    $cheapestLeasingPlans = $this->myCustomService->getCheapestLeasingPlanIds();
    $criteria = $event->getCriteria();
    $criteria->addAssociation('leasingPlan');
    $criteria->getAssociation('leasingPlan')
        ->addSorting(new FieldSorting('price', FieldSorting::ASCENDING))
        ->addFilter(new EqualsAnyFilter('id', $cheapestLeasingPlans))
    ;
}
```

And then you could sort by

```
$criteria->addSorting(new FieldSorting('leasingPlan.periodPrice', FieldSorting::ASCENDING));
```

Comment: Thx. Yes, you are right. I already pointed some of this out in the other comments. :)

It get's interesting, when dealing with multiple sales channels. My solution was: create a new custom field, whenever a sales channel is created. (Done by code with the right event/decorator). Because products might not be available in every sales channel, every sales channel get's his own minimum value. When applying the sorting, check the sales channel first, and choose the correct field to sort by, if the sorting is activated. I keep filters completely out, because I want the default filtering working.

Comment: One thing to add: I choose to use scalar fields, that get calculated, everytime a product get's updated. That way the data is always up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to add the association manually and to add the aggregation to the criteria, that should happen automatically behind the scenes if your custom sorting is selected in the storefront.

For more information refer to the [official docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-sorting-product-listing#create-individual-sorting-at-runtime).

Comment: I tried that, but it sorts in the wrong way. The joined table has multiple entries for one product (n:m), and I want to get the search result ordered by the lowest value of a specific field from the joined table.

So some prices are in the right order, and some are mixed up. I get them in an order like: 29, 79, 114, 99

(It seems to do it, like if you do a join on a foreign table, not keeping in mind that you would have to order the table you want to join before the join, to get the correct values in the fields you want to order by)